# How do you wrap your head around Bixby Programming?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

grettings.

I am new to this forum so if I made any mistakes please inform me.

So I am here today because I can't wrap my head around the bixby developer documentation. I am trying to build an capsule but every time I try to learn specifics about a subject, I get either distracted learning the complementary features or lost thinking how as specific features plays its role in an app. The documentation mainly focuses on details and technical jargon for the feature but not its role.

For e.g I am trying to build an  `action (FindTheQuotes)` but as I am referencing to dev docs for bixby language keys (https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/action). I see there is a new key recently added `delegate-to` it tells you more about it in details but it dosen't mention how that piece fits into the big puzzle. Hence, I was asking the question: "How do you make sense of bixby as whole in general?" and if you have a visual graph for me to look at then that would be wonderful.

Comment: Hi Nilay, Welcome to stack overflow. Unfortunately your question is a bit broad for this site. If you have more specific questions I'm sure there are plenty of people here who can help - otherwise I'd suggest working your way through the documentation and repeating the process until you have some clarity.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO. As George said, it is a very broad question. However just to share my experience, I started with https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/get-started/overview and then tried few of the sample Capsules available to understand concepts first hand.
As the code runs on remote server, the IDE Debug console helped me a lot in understanding the flow and system behavior.

The sample capsule collection on github has several examples to look for inspiration or imitation :). 
https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-samples-collection

Comment: Hello, Mohana. I indeed tried those things beforehand. However, I am more curious how you used Debug Console to understand the flow and system behavior. Tips on that would be more helpful for me for right now.

Answer (score 0):

That is a broad question. Two additional resources that I suggest. The first would be our YouTube channel https://www.youtube.com/c/bixbydevelopers

I suggest viewing the Bixby 101 video and the Hello World video.

The second would be use the new template feature. This is a wizard to auto-generate code and an excellent starting point. See https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/sample-capsules/templates